# How can I wrap widget templates in Meteor?

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

Say I have a widget that is going to display a graph and another widget that will display a table in a typical dashboard.  Because of the consistency of the widget's outter controls, I want to put the bootstrap panel in a template that displays consistently for all widgets, similar to the template below:

```
<template name="widgetBox">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        {{this.title}}
        <span class="pull-right clickable" data-effect="fadeOut"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></span>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <!-- I want the widget to go here -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

I'm not sure how to do this by iterating over a collection, because I would like to control the appearance of each of the widget bodies with their own template.  For instance two table view widgets might share a template that includes sorting or filtering, while two graph widgets would have completely different requirements and layout.

Is it possible to use boilerplate html like the "widgetBox" template above while placing another template inside the panel-body?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want one outer template to reuse multiple inner templates you can either use a *router* and a `{{> yield}}` pattern **or** use [dynamic templates](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_dynamic)

The former is typically used for master page layouts although you can have multiple yield's inside a layout.

The latter may be better suited for widgets.

```
{{> Template.dynamic template=myTemplateName [data=data] }}
```

where `myTemplateName` is the name of a helper function that returns a string corresponding to the name of a template you've created.